# C program to calculate tax brackets using loops but no arrays

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement

I have an assignment and it requires me to have functions with these requirements:

1. `Tax_Bracket_Identification`. This function will identify the tax bracket. This function:

   - is of type int;
   - has one call-by-value argument (income);
   - uses nested if-else statements.
2. `Tax_Calculation`. Will calculate the tax for each income scanned and:

   - is of type void;
   - has three arguments:

     - the income (call-by-value);
     - the tax bracket (call-by-value);
     - the tax (call-by-reference);
   - uses a switch case statement to calculate the income tax.
3. `PrintAll`. This function will print the tax bracket and income tax. It:

   - is of type void;
   - has two arguments:

     - the tax bracket (call-by-value);
     - the income tax (call-by-value).

So basically, I've started the assignment and I have a few questions.
Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int taxBracketIdentification(int);
void taxCalculation(int income, int taxbracket, int *tax);
void printAll(int, int);
int taxbracket;

void main() {
int  incomenumber, income, *tax;

printf("Please type in the number of incomes to be processed. \n");
scanf("%d", &incomenumber);
printf("Please type in the income \n");
scanf("%d", &income);

}

int gradeone, gradetwo, gradethree, gradefour, gradefive, gradesix;
int taxBracketIdentification(int income) {
int taxbracket;

if (income < 10000) {
   taxbracket = 1;
}

    else if (income > 10000 && income < 20000)
    {
   taxbracket = 2;
    }

   else if (income > 20000 && income < 30000)
    {
   taxbracket = 3;
   // printf("your tax bracket is 3");
    }
   else if (income > 30000 && income < 40000)
    {
   taxbracket = 4;

    }
    else if (income > 40000 && income < 50000)

    {
   taxbracket = 5;
    }

    else if (income > 100000)
    {
   taxbracket = 6;
    }

}

void taxCalculation(int income, int taxbracket, int *tax) {

(taxBracketIdentification(income));
switch(taxbracket) {
case 1:
    *tax = (0.05 * income);
    break;
case 2:
   *tax = 500 + 0.10*(income - 10000);
   break;
case 3:
   *tax = 1500 + 0.15*(income-20000);
   break;
case 4:
    *tax = 3000 + 0.20*(income-30000);
    break;
case 5:
    *tax = 7000 + 0.25*(income-50000);
    break;
case 6:
    *tax = 19500   + 0.30*(income-10000);
    break;

}

void printAll(int taxbracket, int tax)
{

printf("Your tax bracket is: \t %d \n", taxBracketIdentification(income));
printf("Your tax is \t %d \n", );




}



}
```

Now I have several questions...

- 1) How do I receive multiple inputs from the user without using
  arrays? Is this even realistic?
- 2) The prerequisites of my functions    states that I have to use a
  call by value parameter in the printAll    function, however I'm
  using a call by reference parameter in the    taxCalculate. How would
  this even work? Am I to call the calculating    function in main,
  then store it as a value so that this value can be    called by the
  printAll function?
- 3) Am I doing this assignment    properly and are there any mistakes
  that are noticable off the bat.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your title starts with  C program. Dont you think it would be a good idea to include the `C` tag? Not only so people who know C can find it but also so your code has the appropriate highlighting

Comment: Okay sorry about that, thanks for adding it in for me

Comment: Looks like you have some holes in your if statements. For instance if you earn precisely $20000 you don't get a bracket or between $50000 and $100000. I would put the brackets in an array of structs with the bracket and rate (hash?), then  loop through them and break out when you found one. If it says just to use call by value in the printAll you are good. Doesn't really matter where you call the printAll imho, main or taxCalculate. If you plan to extend the program later, it might make sense to return the value. I would maybe put the bracket calculation in the taxCalulate function, cleaner.

Comment: Few other things wrong: in taxCalculate shouldn't it be income-100000? Missing last 0. And it looks like income is needed in the printAll

Comment: BTW, if you *were* using arrays, you'd have an array of brackets.  You'd search for the first element greater than your input.  (linear search or binary search).  You'd use that position as an index into another table of constants for the tax-calc formula.  This would be a "data driven" approach to coding it, instead of hard-coding all the constants into `if()` conditions.  Hopefully your professor will later use the rules of this assignment as an example of bad coding practice that mixes the data in with the logic.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific questions:

1/ You don't need arrays if you receive items from the user and *process them immediately.* You only need arrays if you want to store the information for later use. For example, this pseudo-code outputs double whatever multiple items the user inputs despite not having arrays to store the values:

```
val = get-input()
while val != -1:
    output(val * 2)
    val = get-input()
```

2/ A variable itself isn't call-by-value or call-by-reference, it's how you *pass* it to a function that dictates that. For example, the following C code passes it using both methods, first to set it to a specific value then to output it:

```
void setTo42 (int *pVal) {
    *pVal = 42;
}
void outputIt (int val) {
    printf ("%d\n", val);
}
:
int xyzzy = 7;
setTo42(&xyzzy);    // pass by reference (emulated).
outputIt(xyzzy);    // pass by value.
```

3/ The way you're doing the assignment seems fine but I'll give you two pieces of advice. First, think about what your code will give you as a tax bracket for an income of `20000`. To be less obtuse, you're going to have to use `<=`/`>=` rather than just `<`/`>`. Second, consider a construct like:

```
if (xyzzy < 20000) {
    doLt20k();
} else if ((xyzzy >= 20000) && (xyzzy < 40000)) {
    doGe20kLt40k();
} else {
    doGe40k();
}
```

In that code, the second `if` statement is needlessly complex since it will never be checked when `xyzzy < 20000`. Hence it can be reduced to the simpler:

```
if (xyzzy < 20000) {
    doLt20k();
} else if (xyzzy < 40000) {
    doGe20kLt40k();
} else {
    doGe40k();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However in regards to my second question, why is it that when i call my printAll function it tells me that it still expects a pointer variable? would my function call be something like this?: printAll(tax, income);

Comment: @BodyBingers, note what I did in the call-by-reference code in my example: `setTo42(&xyzzy);`. You have to pass a *pointer* to the value (and dereference said pointer within function: `*pInt`) - that's because C doesn't yet have pass by reference except in an emulated fashion. In you specific case, declare `tax` as `int tax` (not `*tax`) then pass it thus: `taxcalc(income,bracket,&tax);`